# Vue3. Use one var in different methods for auth

Tags: javascript, vue.js, variables, ecmascript-6

It mess me up... I'm frustrated.
How to use the 'validToken' variable to add it to the auth line for headers? It catches the error message (fetchHeaders func)...

I can't understand why the 'axios' authentification doesn't work for auth request (returns 'headers fetched with error!'), but works if I set validToken hardcoded..
It returns me validToken correctly for template...

Pls help!
Thx in advance!

```
    #App.vue
    
    <script>
    import axios from 'axios';
    const FormData = require('form-data');
    const API_URL = "https://my_api_path.com/";
    let data = new FormData();
    data.append('username', 'my_username');
    data.append('password', 'my_password');
    let config = {
        method: 'post',
        url: `${API_URL}/login`,
        data: data
    }
    let validToken = ""
    
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                validToken: "",
                headers: []
            }
        },
        methods: {
            async userLogin() {
                try {
                    await axios(config)
                        .then((resp) => {
                        this.validToken = resp.data.access_token;
                    });
                    Token = this.validToken;
                } catch(err) {
                    console.log(err)
                }
            },
            async fetchHeaders() {
                try {
                    let config = {
                        headers: {
                            Authorization: `Bearer ${validToken}`
                        }
                    }
                    const resp = await axios.get(`${API_URL}/headers/`,
                        config
                    )
                    this.headers = resp.data;
                } catch (err) {
                    console.error("headers fetched with error!");
                }
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            this.userLogin(),
            this.fetchHeaders()
        }
    }
    
    </script>
```

Comment: Just use async-await in mounted. It's validToken in one place and this.validToken in another. Don't use variables for component state.

Comment: @EstusFlask Thx! I'm not really expert in Vue. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed according the @EstusFlask recommendation.
'userLogin' func moved to mounted:

```
    async mounted() {
        await axios(config)
            .then((resp) => {
             validToken = resp.data.access_token
        });
    }
```